# very basic CSS height question

Tags: html, css

I have an image in side the div, and an hyperlink next to it. The problem is that the hyperlink is being displayed at the bottom level of the image. I want to display it in the center of the image.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
<img class="image" src="http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/16149178162137949115.png" alt="smiley" />
<a class="link" href="#">move it up in the center to the smiley</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main{
    border:1px solid red;
}

.image{
    border:1px solid green;
}
.link{
    /*height:30px;*/
}
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/cTRsY/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to put text on the middle of an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580880/how-to-put-text-on-the-middle-of-an-image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.image {
 vertical-align:middle    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
.main{
    border:1px solid red;
}

.image{
    border:1px solid green;
    position:absolute;
}
.link{
    line-height:65px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Setting the position of a image to absolute means any element will float over it. Then on text/link setting line-height is basically the height so we match the image height. Its also good to set the text/link position to relative to be sure so it will work in IE also.